# Remove HTML Markup from YouTube RSS Feed Import

Tags: feeds, files

Drupal newbie here- using D7 Commons on a WAMP Development setup (for now).

I am importing an RSS feed from YouTube (using Feeds & Media: YouTube modules). It's working great, except that the description text is inserting all the  markup tags in the description text. I have tried setting the field text to simple text and filtered html, but neither eliminates the markup tags.

Q: Is there a way to import the description text without all the HTML markup tags?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to configure the Text format setting Node Processor section of the Feed Importer found at admin/structure/feeds/[importer name]/settings/FeedsNodeProcessor, but there has to be more to your configuration that may be impacting this.  HTML tags/brackets are not allowed in the description of YouTube videos.

[image: HTML tags not allowed]

So I'm not even sure what HTML you are referring to.  I'm only aware of 3 options to get access to a list of YouTube videos formatted as RSS.

1) https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UC194cPvPaGJjhJBEGwG6vxg/uploads?v=1

2) https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UC194cPvPaGJjhJBEGwG6vxg/uploads?v=2

3) Using version 3 of the API as described in https://www.drupal.org/node/2181067.  That configuration requires OAuth.

In option 1 and 2, replace UC194cPvPaGJjhJBEGwG6vxg with account name you want a feed for.  In both those options, the description text is in the element...

```
 <media:description type='plain'>
```

That element cannot be mapped with just Feeds, Media and Media: YouTube.  You'd need something like https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_mediarss

There may be another way to access the RSS, but without knowing what you are using it's impossible to provide a better answer.  As long as the Feeds Parser and Processor acknowledge the text format setting in the Feed Importer, the resulting nodes should only have plain text in their body fields.